# Error: Not authorized to use background location services

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, geolocation

I am about to finish an app that uses expo location services. My app need to track the position of the user even when the app is closed but I get this error : `Error: Not authorized to use background location services.`. On my android phone I activated all the autorisation : Always access to location (even when the app is closed), use of exact position are all checked.

In my app.json here are my permissions :

```
      // NEW
      "permissions": [
          "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
          "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
          "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        ]
```

and in my App.js file here is how I get the permissions (inside a useEffect hook):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //...

    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
//...
    })();
  }, []);
```

I didn't fully understand the expo documentation about this. Tell me if you need to see other files. You are my last solution.

Comment: Are you sure already add this line of code ```const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});``` to get the GPS coordinate??

Comment: @FelixFilipi yes I use it letterin the ´//...´ part do you want to see this code ?